# Loading different image service functions to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, image-mosaic, image-service

If someone has created an image service in ArcGIS with function templates in order to process on the fly... How would you bring that data into QGIS and be able to switch between functions?  In ArcMap you open the properties and select the functions tab... But how would one do this in an OpenSourceGIS utilizing the Image Service?

PS it can be accessed through a WMS/ WFS

But is the 'functions template' an ESRI only product when dealing with image services??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't....

But you can bring the imagery in. If the server you are connecting to publishes the imagery as  a WMS then of course you can add it into QGIS the same as any other WMS. If the server publishes the REST interface only then you can add it using the Python console. Details on how to do this can be found [here](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Arcgis_rest).

To get the ability to call the Image Service and implement one of the functions then you will need a plugin created to do this. It looks relatively straight-forward as in essence it is just a JSON formatted message to the Image Service.

Comment: perfect, and if the user isn't capable of utilizing the Python Console, then they can just use the raw DEM and produce derivatives on their own fairly easily.  It's simply a DEM with functions: slope, aspect, hillshade, stretchedMeters, and feet conversion... Not too difficult to perform on your own... Thanks for the help!